# Faceswap : Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "faceswap.py", line 33, in <module>
    ARGUMENTS.func(ARGUMENTS)
  File "D:\Projects\faceswap\lib\cli.py", line 36, in execute_script
    script = self.import_script()
  File "D:\Projects\faceswap\lib\cli.py", line 25, in import_script
    from scripts.train import Train as script
  File "D:\Projects\faceswap\scripts\train.py", line 9, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime. [link here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems)

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of you might be using 32-bit Operating system or 32-bit Python. Also check does your CPU support AVX instruction set.
Make sure all the dependencies given on [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements) are installed correctly.